# What is a circle classified as?

Tags: geometry, definition, circles

A circle is not a polygon because it is not solely comprised of line segments. If this is true, then what is a circle classified as? Is there a group of shapes that includes shapes with curves?

Comment: A circle is a set of points which are equidistant from a given point called the centre.

Comment: But is there a special name for the category that also includes shapes like ellipses and the twitter logo?

Comment: A simple closed curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a simple closed curve, or a Jordan curve, which is just a nice loop in the plane.  If you talk about symmetry properties, you can separate it from that large category.  It is a smooth curve because it is differentiable, unlike the Twitter logo.  It is also a 1-sphere because it is one dimensional and consists of all the points within a plane that are a given distance from a center.

Comment: Can we call it a 1-ellipsoid, because a circle is an ellipse with eccentricity zero?

Comment: @learning:  A circle is certainly an ellipse.  I haven't heard the term 1-ellipsoid, but it makes sense.

Comment: I haven't heard it either, but I just "generalised" ellipses to n-dimensions (so n-dimensional ellipsoids) and then 1-ellipsoid like a 1-sphere. As you said, it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

'Conic sections' ? This includes hyperbolae, parabolae and ellipses (circle is a special case of ellipse).